# Binding Expression in Aurelia if.bind

Tags: aurelia, templating

I would like to put in a simple expression to a template in Aurelia.

When working in a loop of `<span repeat.for="link of links">`, I want to show a '/' between all items, except after the last one.

I would expect I could use the following:

`<span if.bind="${$index + 1} !== ${links.length}"> / </span>`

But this gives me the following error:

`Uncaught (in promise) Error: Parser Error: Missing expected : at column 10 in [${$index + 1} !== ${links.length}]`

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `if.bind="$index !== links.length - 1"` instead of doing string interpolation. That should make it work.

Comment: Good call, thanks! Makes sense now that I think about it and it isn't super late at night.

Answer (score 2):

or even shorter:

```
<span>${links.join(' / ')}</span>
```